# Change < Mutation > into useMutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo

I have a removeUser page where I am using a < Mutation > and then I am doing my error handling using the `submitForm()` function. This code worked perfectly well:

```
export default function RemoveUserPage() {
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [isRemoved ,setIsRemoved] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  function StatusMessage(){
    if (isRemoved){
      return (
      <CustomAlert severity='success' text='User Removed'></CustomAlert>
        )
      }
   //else...
  }

  function submitForm(RemoveUserMutation: any, email: string) {
    setIsSubmitted(true);
      RemoveUserMutation({
        variables: {
            email: email,
        },
    }).then(({ data }: any) => {
      setIsRemoved(true);
    })
    .catch((error: { message: string; }) => {
      setIsRemoved(false);
      console.log("Error msg:" + error.message);
      setErrorMessage(error.message)
    })
  }

  return (
    <Mutation mutation={RemoveUserMutation}
    >
      {(RemoveUserMutation: any) => (
    <div>
      <PermanentDrawerLeft></PermanentDrawerLeft>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ email: '' }}
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            actions.setSubmitting(false);
          }, 1000);
        }}
        validationSchema={schema}
      >
        {props => {
          const {
            values: { email },
            errors,
            touched,
            handleChange,
            isValid,
            setFieldTouched
          } = props;
          const change = (name: string, e: any) => {
            e.persist();
            handleChange(e);
            setFieldTouched(name, true, false);           
          };
          return (
            <div className='main-content'>
              <form style={{ width: '100%' }}
               onSubmit={e => {e.preventDefault();
                submitForm(RemoveUserMutation, email)}}>
                <div>
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ""}
                    error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
                    label="Email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={change.bind(null, "email")}
                  />
                  <br></br>
                  <Button
                  type="submit"
                  disabled={!isValid || !email}
                  >
                    Remove User</Button>
                </div>
              </form>
              <br></br>
              {isSubmitted && StatusMessage()}
            </div>
          )
        }}
      </Formik>
    </div>
      )}
     </Mutation>
  );
}
```

However, I was suggested to use `useMutation`instead. Firstly, I am unable to do so since I get such errors:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): GraphQL error: Variable `email` of type `String!` must not be null.
```

And even if the mutation works, is there any way I can still modify and use the same function for error handling in my case?

This is what I was trying now but this doesn't work:

```
export default function RemoveUserPage() {
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [isRemoved ,setIsRemoved] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  const [removeUser] = useMutation(RemoveUserMutation);

  function StatusMessage(){
    if (isRemoved){
      return (
      <CustomAlert severity='success' text='User Removed'></CustomAlert>
        )
      }
  }

  function submitForm(RemoveUserMutation: any, email: string) {
    setIsSubmitted(true);
      RemoveUserMutation({
        variables: {
            email: email,
        },
    }).then(({ data }: any) => {
      setIsRemoved(true);
    })
    .catch((error: { message: string; }) => {
      setIsRemoved(false);
      setErrorMessage(error.message)
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <PermanentDrawerLeft></PermanentDrawerLeft>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ email: '' }}
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            actions.setSubmitting(false);
          }, 1000);
        }}
        validationSchema={schema}
      >
        {props => {
          const {
            values: { email },
            errors,
            touched,
            handleChange,
            isValid,
            setFieldTouched
          } = props;
          const change = (name: string, e: any) => {
            e.persist();
            handleChange(e);
            setFieldTouched(name, true, false);           
          };
          return (
            <div className='main-content'>
              <form style={{ width: '100%' }}
               onSubmit={e => {e.preventDefault();
                removeUser({variables: {todo: email }});}}>
                <div>
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ""}
                    error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
                    label="Email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={change.bind(null, "email")}
                  />
                  <br></br>
                  <Button
                  type="submit"
                  disabled={!isValid || !email}
                  >
                    Remove User</Button>
                </div>
              </form>
              <br></br>
              {isSubmitted && StatusMessage()}
            </div>
          )
        }}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason to have a `RemoveUserMutation` anymore -- `removeUser` is already in the scope, so just use it.

```
function submitForm(email: string) {
  setIsSubmitted(true);
  removeUser({
    variables: {
      email,
    },
  })
  ...
}
```

You can continue to use your `submitForm` function like this:

```
onSubmit={e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  submitForm(email);
}}
```

This line

```
removeUser({variables: {todo: email }})
```

isn't working because there is no `todo` variable. Since your using TypeScript, you should generate type definitions for your queries and then use them with the hooks. This would prevent mistakes like this.

Comment: If I am using my ```submitForm()```on ```onSubmit()```, I no longer need ```removeUser({variables: {email}});```over there right? From what I understand, the actual mutation will now work only from the function. Am I correct?

Comment: removeUser will work anywhere in your component, including inside any functions you declare after it